# Convert from JSON formatted string to downloadable JSON file

Tags: php, html, json, laravel

I start with an Array:

```
$arr = array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => Input::get('symptom'),
            'amount' => 5,
            'time' => '2:00 am',
            'date' => '10.26.96',
            'type' => 'symptom',
        )
```

I save it to the user:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->json = json_encode($arr);
```

Then downloading it:

```
<form method="get" action="json.json">
    <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

How can I allow the user to download the contents of `Auth::user()->json?`
Any help is appreciated!

PS I am using Laravel but I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a file then put this path as follow

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->json = json_encode($arr);
$path = public_path('json.json');
$file = File::put($path,$user->json);
return Response::download($path);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where is `pathToFile` coming from?